# Treating JSON array as a String to insert into MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, json

say I've got a JSON like this:
`{"name": "tom", "id":1, "clothes":[{"shirt":"yellow"},{"shoes":black},.......]}`
I'm trying to insert it, as is, into a column in a mysql DB using Java.

```
void insertVal(JsonObject json){
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Orders?user=root", "root", "1234");
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        StringBuilder values = new StringBuilder("(");
        for (String key : json.keySet()){
            if (key.equals("clothes")){
            //do something to deal with this array

                break;
            }
            values.append(json.get(key)).append(",");

        }
        values.append(")");
        String insert = "INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES " + values;
        st.executeUpdate(insert);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This code works fine up to `clothes` key.  So far, I've tried using `JSON OBJECT` and `JSON MERGE` but the format doesn't quite match, and I'd rather not parse right now.
So, is it possible to add `clothes` or do I have to parse it somehow? if so, what format would work best?
Thanks a lot

Comment: You may need to clarify your issue.  I don't know what you are asking. What string do you want to insert for cloths?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Honestly, I don't quite mind - what I thought would be easiest is all content between the two square brackets.

Comment: Its a string, place it in the query like you would any string, although preparing and bind the parameters would probably help you

Comment: That doesn't work - Mysql claims syntax issue, and reading through the web, there is an issue with closed brackets and arrays

Comment: please post the error message, there should be the insert query

Comment: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[{"shirt":"yellow" at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To all those concerned: The problem was the `"` string. mysql, and probably SQL in general, don't handle these well. There are two options. The first, and less recommended:
`String parsed = json.get(key).toString().replace("\"", "");` 
Then, insert normally.
The second, much more recommended - use `PreparedStatement`. This way, you can write an insert/update query without minding the escape characters. Example, after i've inserted 'null' values for the `clothes` column:

```
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE ORDERS set CLOTHES = ?  WHERE ID = ?");
            ps.setString(1, clothes); // clothes - get(key).toString()
            ps.setInt(2, count); // count - counts which iteration we are
            ps.executeUpdate();
```

I hope anyone in the future finds this useful.